# Postgres \u representation to readable representation

Tags: sql, postgresql, encoding, utf-8

I've a column which has data in following format

```
\d my_table
   Column    |           Type           |   Modifiers   
-------------+--------------------------+---------------
 message     | character varying        |
```

`message` has strings such as

```
select message from my_table;
         message         
-----------------------
\u6771
```

How can I print its human readable counterpart `東`? I don't know how to use `E` while selecting columns. I don't have database write access so I can't create functions.

Comment: [PostgreSQL - string functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/functions-string.html)